# How to assign value to variable from json file

Tags: javascript, html, json, xmlhttprequest

There is a folder on my computer with files like `script.js` and `data.json` in it.
In `script.js` there is a variable called `data`.
Content of `data.json` is like:

```
[
  { "key_11" : "value_11",
    "key_12" : "value_12" },
  { "key_21" : "value_21",
    "key_22" : "value_22" },
  { "key_31" : "value_31",
    "key_32" : "value_32" }
]
```

I need to assign whole `data.json` content to var `data` as its value like:

```
var data = [
  { "key_11" : "value_11",
    "key_12" : "value_12" },
  { "key_21" : "value_21",
    "key_22" : "value_22" },
  { "key_31" : "value_31",
    "key_32" : "value_32" }
];
```

(variable `data` here becomes an array with 3 Object-elements).

I do

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "data.json", true);
  xhr.send();
var data = (xhr.status == 200)? "" : xhr.responseText;
```

but it fails with error

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

(in Google Chrome).

How can I properly do this without using JQuery?

Comment: Should work fine in Firefox, if you want to use Chrome you'll need to run a web server

Comment: Are you trying to run the Javascript from a local file? Chrome won't let you use AJAX in local files.

Comment: You're doing an XMLHttpRequest () to your hard disk, rather than against a web server. XMLHttpRequest () is an HTTP call, therefore you need to call a web server, not to a file.

You have two choices: settle a web server on your computer, configure it to accept requests and make the call XMLHttpRequest () to your localhost, or just open data.json and parse the variable data.

JQuery has nothing to do with this case, JQuery is just a library to simplify use of JS and manage the DOM elements more simply

Comment: Firefox says, that it is a syntax error in `data.json`, but http://jsonlint.com/ says `Valid JSON`.